# "catch" process output in order to show it on my form

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my method that starts a process:

```
public class Tshark
{
    public int _interfaceNumber;
    public string _pcapPath;
    Process _tsharkProcess;
    public int _packetsCount;
    public string _packet;
    public string _tsharkPath = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
    public delegate void dlgPackProgress(int progress);
    public event dlgPackProgress evePacketProgress;

    public Tshark(int interfaceNumber, string pcapPath)
    {
        _interfaceNumber = interfaceNumber;
        _pcapPath = pcapPath;
    }

    public void startTheCapture()
    {
        try
        {
            _tsharkProcess = new Process();
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-i " + _interfaceNumber);
            _tsharkProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            _tsharkProcess.Start();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = _tsharkProcess.StandardOutput;

            while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                _packet = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
                OnPacketProgress(_packetsCount++);
            }

            _tsharkProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    private void OnPacketProgress(int packet)
    {
        var handler = evePacketProgress;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(packet);
        }
    }

    public void killProcess()
    {
        foreach (Process prc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("tshark"))
            {
                prc.Kill();
                prc.WaitForExit();
            }                 
    }

    private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs arg)
    {
        string srt = arg.Data; //arg.Data contains the output data from the process...            
    }
}
```

The method startTheCapture() is invoked from the main form :

```
private void btnStartCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged);
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            tshark = new Tshark(2, pcapFilePathSniffer);
            tshark.startTheCapture();

            tshark.evePacketProgress += new Tshark.dlgPackProgress(
                (packet) =>
                {
                    bgWorker.ReportProgress(packet, tshark);
                });
        });

    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {

        });

    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}
```

Now this is from the main form too, I have written ProgressChanged which is supposed to  update my gui but my problem is that this is not working and I cannot figure why.

```
private void bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tshark = e.UserState as Tshark;
    listBoxPacketsSnifferTab.Text += tshark._packet;
    lblPacketsReceived2.Text = tshark._packetsCount.ToString("#,##0");
}
```

Comment: You should never just say, "not working".  What's not working?  What is it doing, and what should it be doing?  If you're getting errors, what are they (in detail).  Having us just guess at what the problem is will likely be unproductive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your DoWorkEventHandler, you call tshark.StartTheCapture() before you hookup evePacketProgress event handler.

The startTheCapture method blocks until the wireshark process exits, so any progress events captured while it's running will be "ignored" in OnPacketProgress because there is no event subscriber (handler == null).

change it to this:

```
bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        tshark = new Tshark(2, pcapFilePathSniffer);

        //hookup event handler before executing method
        tshark.evePacketProgress += new Tshark.dlgPackProgress(
            (packet) =>
            {
                bgWorker.ReportProgress(packet, tshark);
            });

        tshark.startTheCapture();


    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i have made this change but i still cannot "get into" bgWSniffer_ProgressChanged method although the process start

Comment: @DanaYeger you'll have to give more information then. If you break in "OnPacketProgress", does that get called? If Yes, is handler == null? Does handler get correctly called? If No, why not? is there a bug in startTheCapture()?

Comment: because i am new developer and didn't understand what you mean i have update my code and add all my class, i hope it will help